# Writing code on Touch Screen device

Tags: coding-style, ide, touch, usability, touchscreen

I really love touch devices like smart phones, iPad, tablets. As a developer I want to write code on the device directly. IDE on the touch device. How will we write program on the device that has no keyboard only dragging and touching is possible?

Of course, those devices have softkeyboards. But I think it is stupid. Let's say I want to list the current directory I needed to touch 15 times in Python interpreter.

```
>>> os.listdir('.')
```

If 'os' module is on the screen I will touch it and lists of subfunctions will be on the screen argument would be '.' It's just 3 touches on the devices, maybe including "Run" button it would be 4 touches. Do you guys ever dreamed about this kind of development? If dreamed what kind of use case is elegant?

Answer (score 2):

One general problem with this approach is, that you would have to look at the place where your fingers are at all times. That's not optimal for an ergonomic working position. Leaving that issue aside there are a number of possiblities.

**Lego coding**
You could **create blocks of code by** selecting special "**building
   bricks**" in your IDE. e.g.a building block for a set of if/else
   statements, a building block for a for-loop or a building block for a
   new method head and body. You could drag these blocks in your coding
   area and fill out the blanks.

**Use your magic wand**
A useful feature would be **programmable gesture**, like the mouse
   gestures you can configure in firefox. For example you could
   autogenerate setters and getters for a variable by drawing an "s"
   over that variable.

**All those little things**
You could use all those features, that have proven to be very handy in touch based applications, like: multifinger resize, scrolling by using two fingers etc.

**Many other features...**
[Your idea here]
This list can definitely be made much longer

And finally a really **good ergonomic softkeyboard** should be added
   for all tasks, where typing is unavoidable.

Comment: @Melug: I rephrased and reposted your question [here in the Ux-Forum](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14255/how-would-the-touch-screen-ide-developers-dream-of-look-like). Maybe it will get more attention there.

Comment: Thanks for good response. I agree on "good ergonomic softkeyboard". Maybe directly drawing "Abstract Syntax Tree" is another way of doing this.